# How to provide read access to a folder and its files via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rewritecond

This is probably trivially easy but after RTFM'ing and trying several things I seem to be a bit stuck...

The current version "appears" to let me access the directory BUT NOT the files via the browser. (Directory it's Files are all 755 (go+rx) - 644 should be adequate but I'm grasping) - i.e. http://schoolofish.org/html-images/

---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Images/.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/html-images/.* [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Have you checked  `/var/log/apache2/error.log` already?